# How to name list without the last element

Tags: functional-programming, computer-science, theory

Lets assume we have a list `[x,y,z]`

Usually in functional languages and computer since
we can say

- `head`  = `x`
- `tail` = `[y,z]`
- `last` = `z`

but how to name `[x,y]` ?

In other words, how called **reversed tail of reversed list**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term for what you're asking for is the list's `init`, and the converse of the `head` is the `last`. So, you have a symmetry here: `head` and `tail` make up the whole list, as do `init` and `last`.

Sources:

- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:init
- http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#init()